# sass @import "compass/reset" error

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sass

I'd like to use Sass with Compass on my static HTML project, but following the instructions does not work. This is what I did:

```
$ gem install compass
$ cd <myproject>
$ compass install compass .
```

which was following by awaiting:

```
directory ./sass/
directory ./stylesheets/
   create ./sass/screen.scss 
   create ./sass/print.scss 
   create ./sass/ie.scss 
   create ./stylesheets/screen.css 
   create ./stylesheets/ie.css 
   create ./stylesheets/print.css
```

But when I start watching scss `sass --watch sass:stylesheets`, I get an error:

```
error sass/screen.scss (Line 6: File to import not found or unreadable: compass/reset.
```

This msg coherent with @import "compass/reset";

What do I have to do on my Ubuntu to see that compass imports?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `compass watch` instead of `sass --watch sass:stylesheets`. If you're using compass, you don't need to bother with sass command. Just use the [compass command](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/command-line/).

Answer (score 0):

if you really wanted to use sass command i use this code. Considering that you are in your sass directory running the following command.

**sass --watch style.scss:../stylesheets/**

That simply means that I have created a new file called **style.scss** and imported the following files within my style.scss. So sass would only watch a single file. In the above command we wishes to have the generated style.css to be in the stylesheet directory.

again its **sass --watch style.scss:/path-to-output-directory/**

```css
@import "ie";
@import "print";
@import "screen";
```

so in this process sass is only watching single file style.scss for any changes within sass directory files.

I hope this explains well.